# Web8.5: Publication can not save translation specifics changes publication properties

Tags: translation-manager, web8.5, publication

I am unable to save/update translation details within publication properties. When I add the details and hit save, the save notification quickly pops up, then disappears. The notification then remains in the notification center indefinitely, but the properties window remains open and the updates do not save.

I have checked the translation and CME logs, as well as the event viewer and nothing is standing out as the cause.

if I change any item in workflow and translation. it`s working fine.

Any one have solution for this issue.

[image]

Comment: this is usually a cause of the network communication between CMS and TM server, or a database locking up issue. Regular maintenance of server and reindexing table in the DB should prevent this from happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation Manager GUI decommision and working fine now.